# Hanging a floating shelf to ceramic

Tags: shelving, ceramic-tile

[image]

Tried to screw through the ceramic or even Grout. Would not penetrate with a pretty decent drill.

[image]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What drill bit were you trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

I have hung several things on tile and brick; I always go through the grout/mortar. It has usually been pretty easy to drill with a masonry bit.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword...masonry or tile drill bit. The proper drill bit is needed for the surface to be drilled.